# Why does the vector Laplacian involve the double curl of the vector field?

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields

The scalar Laplacian is defined as $\Delta A =\nabla\cdot\nabla A $. This makes conceptual sense to me as the divergence of the gradient... but I'm having trouble connecting this concept to a vector Laplacian because it introduces a double curl as $\Delta \mathbf{A}=\nabla(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{A}) - \nabla\times(\nabla\times \mathbf{A})$. I understand what curl is but I don't understand why it's introduced in the vector Laplacian.

Comment: I don't think that formula is correct. In general the laplacian is the divergence of the gradient; I think the formula you're thinking of is $\Delta A = \nabla (\mathrm{div } A) - \mathrm{curl curl }  A$.

Comment: yes, you are correct - fixed. thanks. i'm still confused how this definition arises.

Comment: I would consider what you wrote as a property of the vector Laplacian, not a definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of Laplacian operator for either scalar or vector is almost the same. You can see it by noting the vector identity
$$\nabla\times(\nabla\times A)=\nabla(\nabla\cdot A)-(\nabla\cdot\nabla)A$$
Plugging it into your definition produces still
$$\Delta A=(\nabla\cdot\nabla)A$$

Answer (score 0):

It can be shown that in Cartesian coordinates,

the *vector* Laplacian of a vector field is 
a vector with components equal to *scalar* Laplacians of respective components of the vector field.

That's why it was also named Laplacian (but vector).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Laplacian